# Invalid Twitter Token authentication - Prime31

Tags: ios, plugins, twitter, twitter-oauth, social-networking

I'm working with the Prime31 "SocialNetworking" plugin which works great in all my apps and I haven't had any issues with it up until now. I've distributed my app to a few testers and there is one tester who is having issue when trying to connect/login to Twitter from within the app.
Whenever he clicks on the Twitter app which will check if he's already logged in and if not, it's meant to show the login dialog window (code below), however it just keeps coming up with a Twitter screen stating that "The request token for this page is invalid" (image below). It's strange cause it doesn't even give him the chance to login/create a new account, it just instantly shows this screen, and it's only occurring for him no one else.

Troubleshooting already tried:
- Checked phone time and date settings are correct
- Tried completely closing and re-openning the application and going directly to the Twitter functionality (within a minute or so of running the Twitter initialize function).
- Tried clearing the cache in the Safari browser
- Tried uninstalling the application and re-installing it

NOTE: He is using an Iphone 4 and does not actually have a Twitter account at all, but one would expect it would still show him the login screen to allow him to login/create a new account.

Code to login to Twitter:

```
if (!TwitterCombo.isLoggedIn())
{
    TwitterCombo.showLoginDialog();
}
```

Error message screenshot:
[image: Login error message]

As always any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Even if you aren't using the Prime31 plugin's any advise would be great :).